# Returning multiple HTML snippets per element of array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typeerror

Edited --

Let's say I have an array of JSON objects:

```
"social":[
      {
        "name":"facebook",
        "className":"fa fa-facebook"
      },
      {
        "name":"linkedin",
        "className":"fa fa-linkedin"
      },
      {
        "name":"instagram",
        "className":"fa fa-instagram"
      },
      {
        "name":"github",
        "className":"fa fa-github"
      }
]
```

How do I create an snippet for each of the objects such that they return

```
<p>{social.name}<p>
```

And I don't want to use map.

This is generalized for a more complicated example, but this seems to be the problem I am facing (i.e. I have the data in the format below and I need to get the property from each of the elements to display and I only have one function)

Comment: Do you mind creating a minimal sample reproducible CodeSandbox to work with?

Comment: Can't see any `.length` method attached in the code snap you provided, it would be great if you post the original with-bug code.

Comment: Hi Sultan, there is no .length method ANYWHERE in my code... it's from the default map method

Comment: @SiddAjmera Hi Sidd, I have edited the question to be more general. Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `social` is a part of the state, you can implement a method that maps each item in the `social` array to a `p` tag:

```
renderSocialNames = () => {
  return this.state.social.map(
    socialItem => <p key={socialItem.className}>{socialItem.name}</p>
  );
}
```

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-render-social-items-in-a-list?file=index.js) for your ref.

Comment: And if I wanted multiple lines in the mapping i.e. <div class-""> <p key={socialItem.className}>{socialItem.name}</p></div>
would it still work?

Comment: Yes, it should. There's no reason it shouldn't as long as you're returning a valid `jsx` element from each iteration in the map operation.

Answer (score 1):

cleaner code :) , this might solve your issue

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Projects extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    //initialize this component with props
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    if (data) {
      const projects = data.map(project => {
        return (
          <a className="cell" data-remodal-target={project.id}>
            <img
              className="grid-image"
              src={project.cover}
              data-aload={projects.cover}
              alt={project.name}
            />
          </a>
        );
      });

      const modals = data.map(project => {
        return (
          <div className="remodal" data-remodal-id={project.id}>
            <button
              data-remodal-action="close"
              className="remodal-close"
            ></button>
            <h1>Remodal</h1>
            <p>
              Responsive, lightweight, fast, synchronized with CSS animations,
              fully customizable modal window plugin with declarative
              configuration and hash tracking.
            </p>
            <br />
            <button data-remodal-action="cancel" className="remodal-cancel">
              Cancel
            </button>
            <button data-remodal-action="confirm" className="remodal-confirm">
              OK
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      });
    }

    return (
      <section id="projects">
        <div className="grid-container remodal-bg">
          {projects}
          {modals}
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Aashish, I tried this. Still doesn't work -- because it's saying projects doesn't exist (i.e. data is empty, but data is clearly not empty when I don't use map)

Comment: hey @Will, add a data ? data.map(here the same project code)  : [];

most probably the data might not have been initalized so it can't be used so the better alternative is to have a default fall back value an empty array

Comment: Didn't work. Can you help me with the question above. I have edited to make it more general

Comment: @Will, use for loop maybe